# Background removal using opencv python

Tags: image-processing

Can some one help me with background removal using OpenCV Python? I Am trying to use it for my OCR project.

The expected sample image is : 
[sample_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQsBj.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Try this sample code for background removal.

## Reading image file

```
img = cv2.imread(Image1.jpg)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

## Convert to grayscale

```
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
```

## Apply the thresholding

we are taking a constant threshold for simplicity.

```
thresh = 127   
im_b = cv2.threshold(img_gray, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
```

## Find the contour of the figure

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image = im_b, mode = cv2.RETR_TREE, method = cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

## Sort the contours

```
contours = sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse= True)
```

## Masking the object based on contour

```
mask = np.ones(img.shape[:2], np.uint8)
mask.fill(255)
cv2.drawContours(mask, contours, contourIdx =0 , color =0, thickness = -1)
new_img = cv2.add(im_b, mask)
cv2.imwrite('masked.jpg',new_img)
cv2.imshow('masked.jpg')
```

Given your sample image, I have aimed to crop out a single detected object, based on contour area.

I hope it helps. Cheers Mate !!!

Answer (score 1):

Use inRange function for select:

```
import cv2 as cv
low_H = 0
low_S = 0
low_V = 220
high_H = 255
high_S = 30
high_V = 255
frame = cv.imread('EQsBj.jpg')
frame_HSV = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
frame_threshold = cv.inRange(frame_HSV, (low_H, low_S, low_V), (high_H, high_S, high_V))
cv.imwrite('out_3.png', frame_threshold)
```

Result:
[image]